# Modifying variable order within a nested function

Tags: r

I would like to have variable control over the order of variables being passed to a function. Best illustrated with the following example;

Say we have the following function where two variables are defined within the local namespace of the function and are passed to a nested function within that namespace:

```
testfunc = function(){

  a=1
  b=2

  return(sprintf('first %s, then %s', a,b))
}
```

Is it possible to define the order of the variables `a` and `b` passed to  `sprintf`?

Perhaps something along the lines of:

**My attempt:**

```
testfunc = function(...){

  a=1
  b=2

  return(sprintf('first %s, then %s', ...))
}

testfunc(...=b,a)
```

Clearly the above does not work because of syntactical problems...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```r
test <- function(ord) {
    l <- list(
        a = "x",
        b = "y"
    )
    args <- c(l[ord], fmt = "%s %s")
    do.call(sprintf, args)
}
test(c(1, 2))
#> [1] "x y"
test(c(2, 1))
#> [1] "y x"
test(c(1, 1))
#> [1] "x x"
test(c(2, 2))
#> [1] "y y"
```